# How to make a loop to link a textbox content to a specific excel sheet with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, textbox, userform

i created a userform for tracking the consumption of a set of products in a warehouse, where the content of each text box will be assigned to a different excel sheet (saving the consumption history) 
i would like to ask if it's possible to make a loop for assigning the content of each textbox to a specific sheet instead of repeating the code several times.
i will be really grateful for your help 
Thank you

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim consobav, consobls, consochar As Worksheet
Dim addnewbav, addnewbls, addnewchar As Range
Dim nombrebavettes, nombreblouses, qttbavettes, qttblouses As Integer


Set consobav = Sheet1
Set consobls = Sheet2
Set consochar = Sheet3
'introduire le nombre introduit dans la text box dans le sheet excel
If nbrbavette.Value = "" Then
qttbavettes = 0
Else
nombrebavettes = CInt(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("H2").Value)
qttbavettes = CInt(nbrbavette.Value)
End If
If nombrebavettes < qttbavettes Then
MsgBox "qtt insuffisante: " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Else
Set addnewbav = consobav.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
addnewbav.Offset(0, 0).Value = qttbavettes
addnewbav.Offset(0, 1).Value = Time & " " & Date
addnewbav.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
End If

If nbrbls.Value = "" Then
qttblouses = 0
Else
nombreblouses = CInt(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("H2").Value)
qttblouses = CInt(nbrbls.Value)
End If
If nombreblouses < qttblouses Then

MsgBox "qtt insuffisante : " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Value
Else
Set addnewbls = consobls.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
addnewbls.Offset(0, 0).Value = qttblouses
addnewbls.Offset(0, 1).Value = Time & " " & Date
addnewbls.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
End If


Set addnewchar = consochar.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
addnewchar.Offset(0, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value
addnewchar.Offset(0, 1).Value = Time & " " & Date
addnewchar.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"

Call display
Call Somme_consommation_globale
Call seuil_commande
Call display
Call resetform
Call saving_PDF

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the next code can be the solution for your problem.
Please let me note that your statement: 
`Dim consobav, consobls, consochar As Worksheet` shows a frequent mistake: consobav and consobls are type variant and only consochar is worksheet. 
Correctly `Dim consobav As Worksheet, consobls As Worksheet, consochar As Worksheet`
The same is in the next two lines.

```
Option Base 1
Private Sub mySub()
    Dim tbAllBoxes() As Variant
    'Put all you textboxes into an array
    tbAllBoxes = Array(ManyText.Controls("Textbox1"), ManyText.Controls("Textbox2"), ManyText.Controls("Textbox3"), ManyText.Controls("Textbox4"))

    Dim shAllSheets As Variant
    'Put all your worksheets into an array
    shAllSheets = Array(Worksheets("1"), Worksheets("2"), Worksheets("3"), Worksheets("4"))
    Dim i As Long
    'Use the pair of textboxes and worksheets
    For i = 1 To UBound(tbAllBoxes)
        ' Example: write the content of textboxes in the sheets in order Textbox1 to worksheet("1")
        shAllSheets(i).Range("A2") = tbAllBoxes(i).Text
        'do whatever you would like
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I am happy that it helped. According to the first one. I used `Option Base 1`, which makes all array to start with index 1. You have not in your code (at least you posted). So I think you starts with index 0, but your cycle with 1, therefore the first (0) is not used.

Answer (score -1):

@Viktor 
First of all, i would like to thank you for your contribution, it really helped me improving my code. 
Here's my code after improving it.
i still have one point still bother me is that the algo works perfectly for all the sheets except the first one. 
i still can't understand why.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call display
    Call mySub
    Call clear
    Call display
    End Sub

```
Private Sub mySub()

    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim tbAllBoxes() As Variant

    'Put all you textboxes into an array
    tbAllBoxes = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox1"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox8"))

    Dim tballLabels() As Variant
    tballLabels = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Label1"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label8"))

    Dim shAllSheets As Variant
    'Put all your worksheets into an array
    shAllSheets = Array(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet4"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet6"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet7"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet8"))

    Dim i As Long
    'Use the pair of textboxes and worksheets
    'Définir les noms des colonnes
    For i = 1 To UBound(tballLabels)
        shAllSheets(i).Range("A1") = tballLabels(i).Caption
        shAllSheets(i).Range("B1") = "Date"
        shAllSheets(i).Range("G1") = "Consommation globale"
        shAllSheets(i).Range("H1") = "Stock Actuel"
        shAllSheets(i).Range("G1") = "Consommation globale"
        shAllSheets(i).Range("J1") = "Seuil de commande"
        shAllSheets(i).Range("O1") = "Date de réception"
        shAllSheets(i).Range("P1") = "Quantité reçu"

        Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(tbAllBoxes)
    If tbAllBoxes(i).Value <> "" Then
        Dim txt, cell As Integer
        Dim addnew As Range
        Set addnew = shAllSheets(i).Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        txt = CInt(tbAllBoxes(i).Value)
        cell = shAllSheets(i).Range("H2").Value
        If txt > cell Then
        MsgBox "Quantité superieur au stock restant de " & "  " & tballLabels(i).Caption
        Else
        'Capturer la valeur introduite par l'utilisateur et les introduire dans le sheet associé
        addnew.Offset(0, 0).Value = tbAllBoxes(i).Value
        addnew.Offset(0, 1).Value = Time & " " & Date
        addnew.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"

        'Vérifier que la quantité introduite est inferieur au stock disponible
        Dim lastrow2 As Integer
        lastrow2 = shAllSheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        shAllSheets(i).Range("H2").Value = shAllSheets(i).Range("H2").Value - shAllSheets(i).Range("A" & lastrow2).Value
        End If
    End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(tbAllBoxes)

    lastrow = shAllSheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    shAllSheets(i).Range("G2") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(shAllSheets(i).Range("A2 : A" & lastrow))
        If shAllSheets(i).Range("G2").Value >= shAllSheets(i).Range("J2") Then
    tballLabels(i).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
    'rouge ===seuil de commande attient
    Call send_gmail
    Else
    tballLabels(i).BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'green
    'vert===== produit disponible en quantité suffisante
    End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub clear() 'effacer les valeurs notés par l'utilisateur aprés la fin de l'opération
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbAllBoxes() As Variant

    'Put all you textboxes into an array
    tbAllBoxes = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox1"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox8"))

    For i = 1 To UBound(tbAllBoxes)
    tbAllBoxes(i).Value = ""
    Next i
End Sub
```